# Auto-Scrolling to Date with VBA in Excel: Can't figure out run-time Error '91'

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that I want, when opened, to go to the second worksheet and scroll and select a cell with the current date. My code currently looks like:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'Determine date of Sunday in current week
 curDay = Format(Date, "d mmm")
'Find that date in Sheet 1 Column A
   With Sheets(2).Columns(5)
    Set s = .Find(curDay)
   End With
 Worksheets("Data").Activate
'Select that cell
 Range(s.Address).Select
End Sub
```

I keep getting the error: "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set" on the second to last line.

I'm definitely a rookie with this stuff and have searched documentation on just about everything I can think of here and can't figure it out. Anyone know the issue or a better way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: what happens if you dont find `.Find(curDay)` , then `s is Nothing`, you need to trap this case. Use `If Not s is Nothing then` , and the following line is `s.Select`. `s.Select` is the sams as `Range(s.Address).Select`. Since you declared `s` as a range, why not just select it ?

Comment: in fact the error indicates that you didn't find anything

Comment: additional suggestions: add `Option Explicit` at the top of Module and declare all Variables with `Dim`, like `Dim curDay as string, s As Range` inside your subroutine. Moreover, in the last line it is enough to write `s.Select`

Comment: @KazimierzJawor I made the changes you suggested and still am getting the same error. Not sure how I'm not finding anything; I have a list of dates in the "d mmm" format in Column E of Sheet 2. Is there another way to do the same thing?

Comment: @ShaiRado Where would I put the `If not S is Nothing then` and the following `s.select` ? Forgive my ignorance!

Comment: @Sean you might not find matches as your dates in the cells are in the same format as `Format(Date, "d mmm")` , so the`Find` is unable to find them

Comment: @Sean can you show the relevant section of your worksheet with dates in them ?

Comment: you should possibly search for whole date, not formatted one

Comment: @ShaiRado I guess a follow up question is why aren't I finding anything? E3:E253 of sheet 2 is all dates in `d mmm` format. E3 is `=date(2016,4,25)` and the following cells are `=E3+1`, `E4+1`, and so on.

Comment: @ShaiRado here's a screenshot. need anything else? [link](http://i.imgur.com/w5y8hIp.png)

Comment: @KazimierzJawor I just changed curDay to `curDay = (Date)` and it still didn't find anything.

Comment: @ShaiRado would it help if I uploaded the file to look at?

Comment: @KazimierzJawor would it help if I uploaded the file to look at?

Comment: @Sean try the code in amy answer below, let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

I think (from the image you sent me) that the cells in Column E (in "Data" sheet) are actualy dates, but formatted to show only the `"d mmm"`.

Therefore, when searching the Range for `Today`'s date, you need to search for a matching `Date`, and not the `String`.

**Note**: If your cells are actualy `String`s representing a date, that's another matter, and I need to modify my code below.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim s As Range, FndRng As Range
Dim curDay As Date
Dim LastRow As Long

curDay = Date

With Sheets("Data")
    ' find last row with data in Column E
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

    ' set the Find search range
    Set FndRng = .Range("E1:E" & LastRow)

    Set s = FndRng.Find(What:=curDay, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
                , LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
End With

' Find was succesful >> found a match for current date
If Not s Is Nothing Then
    Worksheets("Data").Activate
    'Select that cell
    s.Select
Else
    MsgBox curDay & " not found in Column E !"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: here's a screenshot of what's happening: [link](http://i.imgur.com/CXwvcaX.png) I'm pretty bewildered. you can see the cell does indeed = today's date, the code is running, and still somehow not finding the cell. I'm on the right worksheet, in the right column... is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @Sean what's happening ? I can't tell from that image ? is the above code running ?you are not running the code above, look in my code, `curDay = Date` and not `curDay = Format(Date, "D mmm")`

Comment: my mistake. here's an updated image: [link](http://i.imgur.com/jwaNmvX.png) The current cell selected in sheet "Data", in Column E, equals TODAY(). I ran your code and it still returns "12/1/16 not found" despite very clearly that the date is actually there.

Comment: how is that cell (where you have "1 Dec") formatted ? can you check it in Format Cell menu in Excel ?

Comment: yes, here's a screenshot of its format: [link](http://i.imgur.com/BrHpC20.png). I even changed its format to standard date format and the same thing occurs. [link](http://i.imgur.com/viAQAdY.png)